# VStack is increasing the width based on String

Tags: swiftui, vstack

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9KhY.png)

I have tried playing with the padding but no success. Since the string is vertical when you use a larger string the vstack gets wider

```
var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Spacer()
        
                    Text(title.uppercased())
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotateClockwise ? 90 : -90))
                    
                Spacer()
            }//: VSTACK
            .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(12))
            .frame(width: 85)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to answer with certainty, as there is clearly a more complex layout around this element. So this answer may work or I may need to edit it as you give me a bit more info.

But my suggestion is this: because rotation is not part of SwiftUI's layout calculation, I would suggest using an HStack to wrap just the Text() elements and then rotating that entire stack. This of course then will require you to be more hands-on with the way you use the HStack in your overall layout, but will allow you to get regular stack layout dynamics for your Text elements. To get more control you could consider using the new layout protocol. These are [two](https://swiftui-lab.com/layout-protocol-part-1/) [good](https://swiftui-lab.com/layout-protocol-part-2/) tutorials.

Comment: Adding it to the HStack and giving it a fixedSize() worked.
Thanks.